# Include asp.net output in link href tag

Tags: html, asp.net

In the following example I am try to include rel links for multi language support. However the asp parser don't seam to recognize the `<%=Alternate.Swedish%>` if it's found inside a `<link />` tag. This is done on a `Site.master` page.

```
<a href="<%=Alternate.Swedish%>">link</a> <!-- This works just fine -->
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sv" href="<%=Alternate.Swedish%>" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="<%=Alternate.English%>" />
```

Comment: What _is_ `Alternate.Swedish` and how is it "not recognized"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the reason this is not working is because the `<head>` section in your master page has a `runat="server"` attribute.

When having a runat server attribute, any link tags in the head section are turned into `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink` controls in which you can't use the `<%=` syntax.

A work around is to give your link tags IDs and then set the attributes in code like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" debug="true"%>

<script runat="server">                
     void Page_Load() {       
        link1.Href = "SE-se";       
     }
</script>

<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <link rel="alternate"  id="link1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```